# docker restrict communication between containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple docker-compose file where I'm starting two container with activeMQ brokers:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  activemq-external:
    image: rmohr/activemq:5.15.9
    container_name: activemq
    volumes:
      - "/Users/test/messaging/broker/broker-1/conf:/opt/activemq/conf"
    ports:
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
  activemq-interal:
    image: rmohr/activemq:5.15.9
    container_name: activemq2
    volumes:
      - "/Users/test/messaging/broker/broker-2/conf:/opt/activemq/conf"
    ports:
      - "61716:61716"
      - "7161:7161"
```

I want to achieve that the internal container blocks all incoming connections from the external container (or if that's not possible blocks all incoming connections in general), but can communicate out to the external container.

It should simulate a firewall around the internal container to test the activeMQ duplex network connection (https://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html)

I'm on macOS 11.4.

EDIT:
I changed my host to a debian machine. Can I achieve this now with iptables?

Comment: To restrict communication between containers you can use Docker Network, Different Network for different Containers.
According to Docker Docs Containers can only communicate within networks but not across networks

Comment: yeah, I have to communicate from one container to the other though. So it should be possible to communicate only in one way

Comment: then it seems iptables are the only solution, you can accept or block incoming and outcoming traffic from particular IPs from it.